# Kibana 7.7.1 - saved search does not include search string quotations; escaping with %22 does not work

Tags: kibana

I tried to save a query with search query string like:

```
"order cancellation request received for userId = 123"
```

I need the whole string so I quote it with double quotations in the search bar. That query works but only until I save it and share the link.

When I save it with "Save" button top of search bar, or "disk" button at the left of search bar, the page reloads and my quotations are removed; now the results are not the same because the engine matches *any* of the words in the query and gets me more results.

When I check the url, I see this part:

```
...,query:(language:kuery,query:'order%20cancellation%20request%20received%20for%20userId%20%3D%20123'),...
```

Apparently, there are not quotations. So I tried to add `%22` as how they should be encoded in URL, but no avail.

So, why? I expect Kibana to preserve the quotations in the search term.

Or, can someone suggests another kind of syntax which is valid, correct and shareable as an URL?

Answer (score 0):

Nah. I found why.

You should add `%22` inside `'xxxx'` so that it would look like:

```
...,query:(language:kuery,query:'%22order%20cancellation%20request%20received%20for%20userId%20%3D%20123%22'),...
```